# Serve Go API on Linux server

Tags: ubuntu, go, nginx, server

After following a couple of tutorials I am still unable to get my API working properly. It works fine locally but when I add it on a server I just seem to be unable to connect. Can someone please walk me through?

I am using a Ubuntu 18.04 server with NGINX. The API is written in GoLang.

My folder structure is:

> /var/www/example.com/
>
> /var/www/example.com/GoAPI/

Obviously the API is located in the GoAPI folder (I know, naming is bad but its just for learning purposes).

The API uses Gorilla Mux and is serving on ":8000". My front-end is written in Typescript and uses Axios. It tries to connect to "http://example.com/GoAPI/".

I have my standard server block (only have 1 atm) which just defined my servername and "try files" and thats it at the moment. I tried adding a proxy pass but that didn't seem to do anything.

The error I am getting now is "Error: "Network Error" and a CORS error, even though CORS did work locally and I added the CORS methods that Gorilla Mux gives you.

Hope someone can help me out.

Server block file at the moment:

```
server {
  listen 80;
  listen [::]:80;

  root /var/www/example.com;
  index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

  server_name example.com www.example.com;

  location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
  }
}
```

Nginx configuration is just out of the box, I have not changed anything.

My config file looks like this:

```
user www-data; worker_processes auto; pid /run/nginx.pid; include /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/*.conf;

events {    worker_connections 768;     # multi_accept on; }

http {

    ##  # Basic Settings    ##

    sendfile on;    tcp_nopush on;  tcp_nodelay on;     keepalive_timeout 65;   types_hash_max_size 2048;   # server_tokens off;

    server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;   # server_name_in_redirect off;

    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;  default_type application/octet-stream;

    ##  # SSL Settings  ##

    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2; # Dropping SSLv3, ref: POODLE  ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

    ##  # Logging Settings  ##

    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;   error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

    ##  # Gzip Settings     ##

    gzip on;

    # gzip_vary on;     # gzip_proxied any;     # gzip_comp_level 6;    # gzip_buffers 16 8k;   # gzip_http_version 1.1;    # gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

    ##  # Virtual Host Configs  ##

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;   include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*; }


#mail {
#   # See sample authentication script at:
#   # http://wiki.nginx.org/ImapAuthenticateWithApachePhpScript
#
#   # auth_http localhost/auth.php;
#   # pop3_capabilities "TOP" "USER";
#   # imap_capabilities "IMAP4rev1" "UIDPLUS";
#
#   server {
#       listen     localhost:110;
#       protocol   pop3;
#       proxy      on;
#   }
#
#   server {
#       listen     localhost:143;
#       protocol   imap;
#       proxy      on;
#   }
#}
```

Comment: You must provide **much** more information.

Comment: This is probably related to your nginx server config. Can you please post it?

Comment: I will post it in my 1st post (edit). Thank you for your reply :)

Comment: There's nothing here which seems to connect anything to port 8000.

Comment: You're serving your Go binary as a file instead of serving the service it exposes when it's running.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You currently do not have anything set in your Nginx configuration file to connect to the service at port 8000. The easiest and quickest way to do this is to use the ProxyPass directive and add the location context to your configuration file inside the server block.

As an example yours should look something like this

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name example.com;

    location /GoAPI {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000;
    }
 }
```

Remember that whenever you adjust the Nginx configuration file the service must be reloaded/restarted for the changes to take effect. You can also test the files using `nginx -t` to ensure the syntax is correct.

Comment: Thank you so much WithTheWind, I will try this tonight and let you know the outcome. Have previously tried this (without luck) but the location was different then since I followed a online tutorial. Ill give this a try, thanks again!